# Adding external libraries to vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

How to add external library to php project on vscode? I tried to add folder to my "multiroot workspace" but theres no autosuggestions, or vscode cant find definitions from folder i added?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's is no proper support for external libraries as of now.  Addding the folder as a multiroot workspace is the best you can do, but you will face problems and shortcomings. Especially when compared to what other IDEs can do, such as Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the [Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) extension.
2. Open settings and paste `Intelephense › Environment: Include Paths` into the search bar
3. Click on `Add Item`
4. If you've previously added the folder to your workspace (via `Add folder to Workspace`), then remove it. Otherwise it'll break the code completion etc for some reason.

[image]

> The include paths (as individual path items) as defined in the include_path ini setting or paths to external libraries. Can be absolute or relative to the workspace folder. Used for resolving script inclusion and/or adding external symbols to folder.